# Using a variable in jQuery to perform a function

Tags: jquery, variables

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? It doesn't seem to be recognizing the `'#del[' + cid + ']'` selector, at all. Which is the exact name of the ID in my PHP code.

```
$(function() {
    var cid = '<?=$row['c_id'];?>';
    $('#del[' + cid + ']').click(function() {
        alert('clicked!');
        var oldqty = <?=$row['qty'];?>;
        var qtyID = "'" + '#qty' + cid + "'";
        alert(qtyID);
        if ($(qtyID).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).(function() {
                $(this).val(0);
            });
        };
        if($(qtyID).not(':checked')) {
            $(this).(function() {
                $(this).val(0);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Here's the PHP code that implement `$row['c_id']`:

```
echo "<input class=\"number aln_center\" type=\"text\" name=\"qty[" . $row['c_id'] . "]\" id=\"qty" . $row['c_id'] . "\" value=\"" . $row['qty'] . "\" size=\"3\" onchange=\"return validateChgMLQty('qty" . $row['c_id'] . "'," . $row['qty'] . ");\" />\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"telco[" , $row['c_id'] . "]\" id=\"telco" . $row['c_id'] . "\" value=\"" . $row['btelco'] . "\" />\n";
echo "<br />Delete\n";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"del[" . $row['c_id'] . "]\" id=\"del" . $row['c_id'] . "\" />\n";
```

I'm trying to get the value in the input statement to change to "0" if the "Delete" checkbox is clicked and then return back to it's original contents when unchecked. It never even gets to the first alert box, so it has nothing to do with qtyID and when viewing source, the 'var cid' line is populated with the correct integer passed from PHP variable `$row['c_id']`.

Comment: What is `cid`? On what attribute on the element is it found?

Comment: Why does qtyID have `"'"` before and after it?  This will make a string like `"'#ID'"`, which won't work.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what are you trying to accomplish, and we can try to help you out and tell you why such specific thing is not happening.

Comment: Is cid a string? it needs +'es

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing PHP and JS, which will not work. PHP won't be evaluated in the user's browser. It is *preprocessed* by the server and sent as raw HTML/XHTML

Comment: Here's the PHP code that implement $row['c_id']:

Comment: @DevlshOne: Where is the code?

Comment: @cesarsalazar: What are you talking about?  PHP runs server-side, we all know that.  PHP will process this file, and when it sees `<?=$row['c_id'];?>` it will run that, therefore echoing out the value, creating the HTML file.

Comment: @Rocket My bad. I maintain a "loosly coupled" perspective towards server and client side code. I instantly thought about a static JS files.

Comment: @cesarsalazar: I use CodeIgniter so all HTML files are passed through PHP.  I'm spoiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
var qtyID = "'" + '#qty' + cid + "'";
```

This line is a problem.  You shouldn't be adding a quote to the beginning and end of the string.

This will make a string like: `"'#qty6'"`, which will not work in a jQuery selector.

It should just be:

```
var qtyID = '#qty'+cid;
```

This selector:

```
 $('#del[' + cid + ']')
```

Should be:

```
 $('#del'+cid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!

The final solution was:

```
$(function() {
    var cid = "<?=$row['c_id'];?>";
    var oldqty = "<?=$row['qty'];?>";
    $('#del' + cid).change(function() {
        if ($('#del' + cid).is(':checked')) {
            $('#qty' + cid).val(0);
            return;
        };
        if($('#del' + cid).not(':checked')) {
            $('#qty' + cid).val(oldqty);
            return;
        };
    });
});
```